# OnClick PendingIntent in widget sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, widget, onclick, android-pendingintent

I have a widget and 4 buttons on it. The buttons are actually shortcuts to other applications. I've set an onClick pending intent for each of the buttons with this code:

```
Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s);                    
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(curIconId, pi);
```

Usually it works fine, but sometimes it doesn't do anything and in the logcat I see a SendIntentException with the message "Cannot send pending intent".

If I update the widget (i.e. setting the pending intent again), it works fine again.

Any ideas on why it breaks down sometimes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I sent too much data to the remote views (in my case, too many icons). So the update actually failed. There is a size limit on what you can send, don't remember where I read it.

The solution in my case was to update the images with resource URLs instead of the actual images.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that whenever you send RemoteViews to a widget, you need to completely specify the widget.  If you only partially specify the widget, if something causes your widget to be updated (such as a screen rotation) your widget will only be recreated with the most recent RemoteViews.

Here's the link that pointed this out to me http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/95040.html

Comment: it doesn't seem to be related to my problem. My code updates the entire widget, it sets the PendingIntents every time. Also, my home screen doesn't rotate.

Comment: It may not solve the original post problem, but that's exactly the problem I had. Very useful and hard to find answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I can't answer you - I get the same behavior on one coworker's (Motorola) phone, but not other phones.

I **can** point out, though, that your `PendingIntent.getActivity()` `flags` parameter is wrong: that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` needs to go on `Intent i`. The `getActivity()` call wants one of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, `FLAG_NO_CREATE`, `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, or one of the `Intent.FILL_IN_` flags.

I can also mention that my clicks sometimes failed until I used `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. This might be why adding "unique data" helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:
The widget didn't work after rotation. The problem in my widget was that I've overridden
the onReceive method and there touched the view to increment a text value. I solved the problem duplicating the setOnClickPendingIntent was in onUpdate,  in the onReceive either.